# Which Polaroid camera is used in the Instagram logo?

Tags: polaroid, old-cameras

Below is the logo of the app "Instagram". Does anybody know which Polaroid camera they used for it?

[image]

Answer (score -3, accepted):

It looks vaguely like an [SX-70](http://camerapedia.wikia.com/wiki/Polaroid). I doubt they'd copy it exactly, more just 'take inspiration'.

Answer (score 13):

It's [Polaroid Land Camera 1000](http://camerapedia.wikia.com/wiki/Polaroid_Land_Camera_1000).

[image: Polaroid Land Camera 1000]

It's obviously not classic SX-70 because it's not SLR, it has see-through viewfinder.

Comment: That's more than just 'inspiration'. They probably bought the rights to use it.